# How to select optional columns in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I want to run a query on my MYSQL database. Depending on what the values are, I want to select different fields.

For example, if field 'e' is null, then I want to SELECT fields a,b,c,d. If field 'e' is not null, then I want so SELECT fields a,b,c,d,e.

Something along the lines of

```
response = SELECT a,b,c,d (AND e IF e IS NOT NULL) FROM table1 WHERE id = 1;
```

Comment: You can do this with `IF()` or `COALESCE()` as long as you don't mind the column names being the same, regardless of which column value you return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of columns in a query result set cannot change. You can't return four columns on some rows and five columns on other rows from a given query.

You'll just have to write your application code with a condition to ignore the fifth column if it's null.